# Naive question on combinatorics and Diofantine

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I was reading through some stuff about cellular automaton and faced the following problem. Basically, I have three squares, each can contain one number among 1,2 and 3, and I have to consider all possible combinations of such 3 numbers such that they have different mean value.

Doing this by counting is trivial, but was wondering whether this can be put in a more formal way in order to compute the same for more numbers involved. One way is to consider all possible combinations with repetitions, which for the specific case are

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
n+k-1 \\
k
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
3
\end{pmatrix}
=10
\end{equation}

and then ignore all combinations with the same mean value, as (112) and (022).

Is there a way to put this in Diofantine equations? I'm quite ignorant on the topic, but the combinations above can be calculated as all the possible solutions of the equation

\begin{equation}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3
\end{equation}

with $x_i$ the number of times the number $i$ is found in the combination. At this point I'm stuck and cannot continue on imposing the different mean value condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case where you have $n$ squares containing a number from $1$ to $k$, the number of possible combinations with different mean values is simply the number of possible mean values. The smallest mean is $1$, the largest is $k$, and any exact multiple of $1/n$ between these values is possible. That gives $nk-n+1$ options.